# Assigning a scalar value to an empty DataFrame doesn't appear to do anything

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and have a very basic question, please!

On Python v3.6 through spyder:

```
x= pd.DataFrame(columns = ['1','2'])
print(x)
x['1'] = '25'
print(x)
```

From the print statements, the dataframe x does not appear to change. 
My question: What does `x['1'] = '25'` do, if anything?

Comment: It does nothing, because the DataFrame is empty. There is no space it can assign to, so nothing happens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is actually a difference between the semantics of assigning scalars and iterables (think containers such as lists as list-like objects).

Consider,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1', '2'])                                                                                             
df                                                                                                                                  

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 2]
Index: []
```

You've defined an *empty* dataframe without any index (no rows), but only a schema for the columns.

When you assign a scalar to a column, the assignment is broadcast across *all* rows. In this case, since there are none, nothing happens:

```
df['1'] = 123
df

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 2]
Index: []
```

However, assigning a list-like iterable is a different story, as pandas will create new rows for it:

```
df['1'] = [123]
df

     1    2
0  123  NaN
```

---

Now, to understand how scalar assignment works, consider a similar empty DataFrame, but with a defined index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1', '2'], index=[0, 1])
df                                                                                                                                  

     1    2
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
```

it is still "empty" (not really), but now we can assign scalars and the assignment is broadcast,

```
df['1'] = 123
df                                                                                                                                  

     1    2
0  123  NaN
1  123  NaN
```

Contrast this behaviour with that previously shown.

Comment: Pandas must do some type checking on assigning an iterable, because iterables like strings do not follow the same behavior that a list/array do (I'm defining iterable using `isistance(x, collections.Iterable)`

Comment: @user3483203 Thanks for mentioning that, I've edited to make it clear I'm talking about list-like iterables :)

Comment: Okay, thanks,this makes the idea of scalars vs. list-like iterables a lot clearer in my head!